# ASPX Home link v.s my button

Tags: asp.net

I made a default ASPX web app in Visual Studio.  In the top bar there is a Home button you can click and that works.
So I made a similar link with an ImageButton and ~/ as the target so it would do the same as the Home button (clicking the company logo).
If one is in the Register screen and clicks Home it works fine, but if you click my image button you are still locked in the Register as though it thinks you are submitting the form.

I have code in the button callback,

```
protected void LogoButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/", true);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have tried just using the `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your ImageButton in your page by this:

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>" >
    <img src="<%= ResolveUrl("image url...") %>" alt="Home">
</a>
```

So you dont need any code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I found that because the image is a button it causes a submit, but the Home link is a ref.  I made the ButtonImage just an Image and wrapped it in a anchor link.